# redux saga put not dispatching action

Tags: enzyme, jestjs, redux-saga

I'm trying to to do integration tests, by mounting a smart connected component.
The fetch action that is within `componentDidMount` of my smart components dispatches just fine, and it's taken by my Saga. Although it is supposed to put a success action, it doesn't .
Here is my testing code :

```
   import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
import Enzyme,{ mount,render } from 'enzyme'
import Tasks from '../containers/tasks.jsx'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import axios from "axios";
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import mySaga from '../actions/tasksSaga'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import reducer from '../reducers'


Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('App', () => {
  // create the saga middleware
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    const state = {
      tasksReducer:{
        tasks:[]
      },
      uiReducer :{

      }
    };

    const todos = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'todo1',
        description: 'nice'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'todo2',
        description: 'nice'
      }
    ]
  
    beforeAll(() => {
      mock.onGet('http://localhost:9001/tasks').reply(200, {tasks:todos})
    })
  
    it('renders an App container', () => {
      const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
      )
      sagaMiddleware.run(mySaga)
      const wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Tasks />
        </Provider>
      )
      
      wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()

      expect(wrapper.find('Task')).toHaveLength(3)
     
    })
  })
```

My success action is never called although data is good.

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to test the success action.  Does the success action put as expected in the app outside of the test env?

Comment: I would put some `console.log` to try to see if it is raising any exception inside the saga.